# Java JXTreeTable tab character support

Tags: java, swingx, jxtreetable

Is tab character(\t) or Tab Key is supported in JXTreeTable? As I am entering some input like "My Name" where the space between My & Name is not through spacebar instead it is using the Tab key from the key board. Now when I am seeing this input in JXTreeTable, I am only able to see as MyName. Without Tab space in it, can any one have any inputs regarding this?